# asp.net core 3.1 streaming large file upload - can't prevent model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**=============== UPDATE ===============**

Apologies, but with all the chopping and changing, commenting out and back in again, to try and get this working, I had accidentally stopped the form calling the script in `Create.cshtml`. The form of the View file should actually read as follows:

```
<form asp-controller="Documents" asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="AJAXSubmit(this); return false;">
```

I haven't closed the question, because the script in `Create.cshtml` is receiving a 400 (Bad Request). This appears to be the real problem - but, I cannot understand why it's happening.

If and when I get to the bottom of it, I will update the question. Hopefully, it will be a useful answer to somebody.

**=============== END UPDATE ===============**

I've been following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#upload-large-files-with-streaming to upload large files to a web app. Unfortunately, when I come to use the MultipartReader (`reader.ReadNextSectionAsync`), I get the error `unexpected end of stream, the content may have already been read by another component`.

I've downloaded the sample app (https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples/3.x/SampleApp) and that works fine, but they're using Razor pages and my project isn't.

One notable difference: when running the demo app from github, when I click Upload, to upload the large file, the Controller method is called immediately. However, when I click to upload the document on my app, the browser shows me the file being uploaded, then the Controller method is called.

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET, and I've been banging my head against a brick wall for a couple of days, so any help would be much appreciated.

My relevant code snippets are as follows:

`GenerateAntiforgeryTokenCookieAttribute`: adds antiforgery token to cookie, copied exactly from the example docs

`DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute`: attribute class to prevent form binding, copied exactly from the example docs

`MultipartRequestHelper`: copied exactly from the example docs

`startup.cs`: this is *maybe* where my problem is, as my project is not using Razor pages, and is using Feature folders, so I've deviated from the example. Plus, my project is using Feature folders.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
  services.AddMvc(o => o.Conventions.Add(new FeatureConvention()))
// first part is for feature folders
    .AddRazorOptions(options =>
    {
      options.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
      options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Features/{3}/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
      options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Features/{3}/{0}.cshtml");
      options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Features/Shared/{0}.cshtml");
      options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new FeatureViewLocationExpander());
    })
// FeatureConvention and FeatureViewLocationExpander taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/september/asp-net-core-feature-slices-for-asp-net-core-mvc#feature-folders-in-aspnet-core-mvc
// next part is to prevent form value binding and to add the anti forgery token to the cookie
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
      options.Conventions.AddPageApplicationModelConvention(
        "/Documents/Create",
        model =>
        {
          model.Filters.Add(new GenerateAntiForgeryTokenCookieAttribute());
          model.Filters.Add(new DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute());
        }
      );
    });
...
}
```

My folder structure is as follows:

```
root
|
`-- Features
    |
    `-- Documents
        |
        `-- Create.cshtml
        `-- DocumentsController.cs
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model DocumentCreateViewModel

<form asp-controller="Documents" asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <label asp-for="filename"></label>
    <input asp-for="filename""><input/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label asp-for="file"></label>
    <input asp-for="file"><input/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
  <script>
    "use strict";
    async function AJAXSubmit (oFormElement) {
      const formData = new FormData(oFormElement);
      try {
        const response = await fetch(oFormElement.action, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'RequestVerificationToken': getCookie('RequestVerificationToken')
          },
          body: formData
        });
        oFormElement.elements.namedItem("result").value = 
          'Result: ' + response.status + ' ' + response.statusText;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    }
    function getCookie(name) {
      var value = "; " + document.cookie;
      var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
      if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
    }
  </script>
}
```

DocumentCreateViewModel.cs

```
public class DocumentCreateViewModel
{
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

DocumentsController.cs: is the contents of `UploadPhysical`, copied exactly from the example docs, `UploadPhysical` is renamed to `Create`

```
[HttpPost]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
  if (!MultipartRequestHelper.IsMultipartContentType(Request.ContentType))
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("File", 
      $"The request couldn't be processed (Error 1).");
      // Log error

      return BadRequest(ModelState);
  }

  var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(
      MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(Request.ContentType),
      _defaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
  var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body);
  var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
// ^^^^ this is where the "unexpected end of stream" exception is thrown
```

Comment: According to your view codes, I found your Create.cshtml don't use ajax when post the form data. I suggest you could firstly try to add `onsubmit="AJAXSubmit(this);return false;"` and try again. If this doesn't solve your issue, I suggest you could try to upload your project to the github to let us test. Notice: Please remove all personal information and just left the codes which let us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer - I've added an update to the question. I am now getting a 400 (Bad Request), so it appears the problem lies between the form post (now done by AJAX) and the Controller, `DocumentsController`.

I'll see if I can get to the bottom of the 400, but if not, I will do as you suggest and post to GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, thank you to @Brando Zhang for getting me back on track.

The problem, the 400 (Bad Request), was due to `DocumentsController` attempting to verify an anti-forgery token that didn't exist - which was down to me unsuccessfully porting the Razor example into MVC.

In the example code, in `startup.c`, the following section is only applicable to Razor pages - not MVC:

```
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
  options.Conventions.AddPageApplicationModelConvention(
    "/Documents/Create",
    model =>
    {
      model.Filters.Add(new GenerateAntiForgeryTokenCookieAttribute());
      model.Filters.Add(new DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute());
    }
  );
});
```

Therefore, that could be removed. However, now there is not anti-forgery token being generated, so when a POST is made to `Create()` in `DocumentsController`, no token is present, so an HTTP 400 is returned.

The solution is a simple one (although it took me long enough to find it!): add `[GenerateAntiForgeryTokenCookie]` to the GET method that presents the form in `DocumentsController`:

```
[HttpGet]
[GenerateAntiForgeryTokenCookie]
public IActionResult Index()
{
  return View("Create");
}

[HttpPost]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
  if (!MultipartRequestHelper.IsMultipartContentType(Request.ContentType))
...
}
```

Hope it helps!